# Optimize checking gzcompressed file for changes

Tags: gzip, crc

I have function which stores data in gzcompressed files, like

```
function savedata($fileName,&$data){
    file_put_contents($filename,gzcompress($data));
}
```

**I want to optimize and don't save if the data is same** as in already stored gzcompressed file.

I can open the whole file, uncompress it and compare with the `$data`, but I think there should be some other way.
Probably gz-d data has some crc or something like that, so I can just compress the data, fetch the crc from it and compare it to the crc in already existing file or something like that.

So I just want to omtimize checking the file and `$data` for changes to make it quicker.

Comment: PHP? You should mention the language, or at least have a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gzcompress()` in PHP compresses to the zlib format, not the gzip format.

Each zlib stream ends with a four-byte check value, though not a CRC. You can compare those to see if two streams are different. However if the two check values are the same, you cannot conclude that the streams are the same.